# C# - How can I see the post-transform XML before signature?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm just doing some cross-language debugging of some SAML scripts, and I have the code working in C# but not in another language and I'm trying to compare the outputs to figure out where I'm missing something. The problem seems to be in the final signature (the digest value is correct). My C# code looks like this:

```
XmlElement element = ...;
SignedXml signedXml = ...; // A SignedXml instance for the element above

var reference = new Reference("#abc");
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());

signedXml.AddReference(reference);
signedXml.ComputeSignature();
...etc...
```

What I'd like to do is simply see the XML -AFTER- the transforms have been applied, so I can see the exact string that C# is signing with ComputeSignature().

Is there a way to dump that string?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a debug log built into SignedXml that just needs to be activated via diagnostics. In my app.config file, I added the following XML inside the configuration node:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml" switchName="XmlDsigLogSwitch">
      <listeners>
        <add name="logFile" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <switches>
    <add name="XmlDsigLogSwitch" value="Verbose" />
  </switches>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="logFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="XmlDsigLog.txt"/>
  </sharedListeners>
  <trace autoflush="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="logFile" />
    </listeners>
  </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

This logged the XML signing debug log, including post-transform output to the console and also to a file called XmlDsigLog.txt.